# API for merge and create branch in Azure Devops for TFVC

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, tfvc

Warm greetings for the day. Hope you all are good.
We are looking for REST API's to do code **merge, branch and check-in** for **TFVC** in **Azure Devops**. Couldn't find, can anyone guide us?
We got REST API for getting a changeset by using the below mentioned link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 0):

We seem do not have the REST API to do these things.

I recommend that you can try using the related [**TFVC commands**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops) to do these things.

Below are some TFVC commands you may need to use:

- [**tf checkout**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command?view=azure-devops)
- [**tf branch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops)
- [**tf merge**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops)
- [**tf checkin**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=azure-devops)